# fetching data from SQL server and print it out using loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to fetch all the data rows in a sql server to print all the values. Here is the code I already tried but it still does not work. Can someone tell me what is wrong here? I'm quite new to vb.net

```
For i = 1 To 100

    Dim testsection As String = e.Item.DataItem("sectionName")
    e.Item.Cells(4).Text = strSection & testsection
    Next
```

i dont quite understand how it fetch the data. i juz work as a fresh grad. but they already assign me this advance task. here is the codes in my DBFunction.

```
Public Function GetUserList(ByVal strUserLogin As String, ByVal strName As String, _
                            ByVal intCompanyID As Integer, ByVal tblName As String) As DataSet
    Dim oConn As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim SQLStr As String = ""
    Dim SubSQL As String = ""
    Dim CMD As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        oConn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        oConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        oConn.Open()
        CMD = oConn.CreateCommand
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SQLStr = "sp_tblUser_Get"

        'CMD.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intCompanyID
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@LoginID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strUserLogin
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strName

        'If strUserLogin <> "" Then
        '    SubSQL = " AND u.UserLogin = " & SQLS(strUserLogin)
        'End If
        'If intCompanyID <> 0 Then
        '    SubSQL = " AND u.CompanyId = " & SQLN(intCompanyID)
        'End If
        'SQLStr = "select u.ID, u.UserLogin, u.Name, c.CompanyName, u.CreateDate from tblUser u " & _
        '    " inner join tblCompany c on u.CompanyId = c.ID WHERE u.ID <> 0 " & SubSQL

        CMD.CommandText = SQLStr
        DA.SelectCommand = CMD
        DA.Fill(DS, tblName)
        CMD = Nothing
        DA = Nothing
        oConn.Close()
        oConn = Nothing
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        DS = Nothing
    Finally
        If Not oConn Is Nothing Then
            oConn.Close()
            oConn = Nothing
        End If
        If Not CMD Is Nothing Then
            CMD = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    Return DS
End Function
```

Comment: your question is not very clear also can you post exact code which you are using.Because I can see for loop and i variable but it is not used in your code.. nor any database connection.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Basically lines from  `Dim oConn As SqlConnection = Nothing` to `DA.SelectCommand = CMD` are used to create connection with the database and have steps to call procedure having name sp_tblUser_Get.

Then all the required parameters of this procedure are paased using lines

```
CMD.Parameters.Add("@LoginID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strUserLogin
CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strName
```

After that using SqlDataAdapter's Fill method data set is filled with the out put.
Dataset DS can contain single DataTable or multiple Datatables which depends on hot Stored procedure is written.

I am assuming it contains single datatable, then if you want to view data then in you can use.

```
DataTable dt= DS.Tables[0];
```

This dt Datatablw will contain all data.
To display that data you can use loop like mentioned below.

```
        DataTable dt = DS.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            String Name = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Age"]);

        }
```

Comment: let say if i use "DataTable dt= DS.Tables[0];" in aspx.vb, can i use it to loop through all the data inside the table then print out all the data?

Comment: I have updated my answer..but to display all data I would suggest to use data controls in .Net like gridView etc.

Comment: thank you for browsing through all my codes. one more question, can i just print all the string value in database using cell table?

Comment: Yes..you can use table..but not advisable.